# Removing value from Object

Tags: javascript

I have an object that I am trying to remove from a cssProperty that is being passed to an element. I have tried several things with no luck and am at a loss.

The object looks like

```
Object {background-color: "#91eae8"}
```

and I have tried removing it like

```
delete this.cssProps.background-color;

delete this.cssProps[background-color];

delete this.cssProps['background-color'];
```

neither has worked and throws viewModel errors because it doesn't know what I'm doing. I cannot change how the object comes in to have quotes around it or anything similar.

Comment: Yes, that was just me trying everything and anything

Comment: Don't you mean `delete this.cssProps['background-color'];`?

Comment: there is no such operator `remove` in js use `delete`

Comment: Sorry guys, I was typing this while listening to someone talk and he was talking about removing so I wrote remove. My actual code does have delete

Comment: `[...]throws viewModel errors[...]` you should be more specific about the error that is thrown at the place where you do the `delete this.cssProps['background-color'];`

Comment: Are you certain `this` is what you think it is?

Comment: @t.niese It is different verbiage of all three above, but it's just saying it cannot read the property.

Comment: @Marcus Yes, I am positive.

Comment: I asked you about the specific error message for `delete this.cssProps['background-color'];`.  (`delete this.cssProps.background-color;` is equal to `(delete this.cssProps.background)  -  color`  and `delete this.cssProps[background-color];`  is `delete this.cssProps[ background  -  ( color )];` so those to are wrong and as of that their error message is irrelevant)

Comment: Well, if you're certain everything is as it should be but it's still not working, something is amiss. Why don't you post *non-pseudo*, relevant code so people can see what's really going on. Because `var obj = { 'background-color' : '#91eae8' }; delete this.obj['background-color'];` works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

In css there is no such thing as an undefined property. They all have default values. So trying to remove a property doesn't work. Instead you can change the value to a different value to get the behavior you want.

I would try doing one of these

```
this.style.backgroundColor = "inherit";//background will be the same as it's parent
this.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";//background will show what is behind it
this.style.backgroundColor = "inital"; //sets it to the default value
```

Comment: For a `CSSStyleDeclaration` (what I think you are talking about) you have _empty_  properties `""`, you can make a property empty by calling `removeProperty`. The difference between an empty and a default value is, that an empty property won't overwrite the property of another matching rule. The properties of a `CSSStyleDeclaration` are all empty by default.